# Transform data before adding to cache system or after when reading it

Tags: performance, caching, architecture, mapping, transform

I have this situation, which I don't know which could fit better.

I have this **solution** where I **search for soccer players**, I only have their names and teams, but when a **user comes** to my website and **clicks on the player** I will use **detailed information** from the player that I get **from various external providers** (usually based by country).

I know which external provider to use when a call is done, and I pay to the external providers each time I grab data, so to mitigate this, I will try to get the less times possible, so I grab once a user clicks on the player info, and next time if it's in my database cache I will show my cache info. After 10 days I will grab again for the specific player form the external provider as I want the info to be somehow updated.

**I will need to transform different providers data that come, usually, as JSON in my own structure so I can handle it the right way**, I have **my own object structure**, so the fields coming from the external providers fall/map/transform in my code always with the same naming and structure..

So, my problem is to **decide when should I map/transform data coming form the providers**.

1. **I grab data from the provider**, I **transform it** to my JSON structure **and record/keep it in the database cache** system this once with my main structure, and in my solution code all I need is, everytime a user clicks on the soccer player details I get from the database cache this JSON field and convert it directly to object I know how to use.
2. **I grab data from the provider**, **keep it as is** in my database cache system, and in my solution code **everytime someone clicks** to get the soccer player detail info I get the JSON record from my database cache, **I transform it** for my naming and structure, and convert it to object

*Notes:*
- this is a cache database, records won't be kept forever, if in a call I see the record have more then 10 days I will get new data from the apropriate external provider

Answer (score 0):

Deciding the layer to cache data is an art form all its own.  The higher the layer you cache data, the more performant it will be (less reprocessing needed), but the lower the re-use potential will be (different parts of the application may use the same cache, and find value if it hasn’t been transformed too much).

Yours is another case of this.  If you store it as the provider provides it, and you need to change the way you transform it, you won’t have to pay to re-retrieve it.  If on the other hand, you store it as you need it now, you may have to discard it all if you decide to change the transformation method.

Like all architectural design decisions, it's all about trade-offs.  You have to decide what is more important to you and your application.

Comment: thanks @rob-conklin ... this is cache, information will get removed after 10 days, Im more keen for performance than on cost... If transformation/mapping changes will just remove entire cache, transformation change will be something that will rarely happen.